# Windows 7 - bottom of applications hidden by taskbar

Tags: windows-7, resolution

This slight annoyance has been bothering me for some time now...

For some reason, some programs appear vertically too large; the bottom portion will be hidden by the taskbar. And of course, they just have to put buttons down there! In some cases, I can maximize the window and it will fit correctly, but sometimes the Maximize button will be greyed out. Presumably these programs are asking for my screen resolution so they can adjust themselves to fit, and Windows (or not?) is reporting it, but not accounting for the taskbar. Is there something I could do to fix this (hack-ish or not), or is it the fault of these applications' programmers?

I can turn taskbar "auto-hide" on to fix it, but auto-hide bothers me verily so this is only a temporary solution. Alternatively, I could move the taskbar to the side of the screen, but I don't know if I want to do that. :\

Sorry that I can't explain it any better; hopefully someone knows what I'm talking about.

Comment: Are there any applications included with Windows, or freeware, that exhibit this problem?  Until I can see it for myself, it's hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the resolution on the monitor is set lower than the programmers anticipated and part of the window is outside the visible area.  Try adjusting the resolution higher to get a larger desktop and see if the windows are fully visible.  If programmers code their pages to a specific size, a lower resolution than they assume could account for the behavior.

To change the screen resolution, right-click the desktop, select "Personalize".  Click "Display Settings".  Use the slider bar to pick a higher resolution.

Answer (score -1):

I disabled (turned off) all the task bar functions and then the  excel screen appeared above the task-bar including all the bottom tabs. Right click on the taskbar, select taskbar settings and turn off all the functions listed below.
1. Lock the taskbar 2. auto hide the taskbar in desktop mode 3. auto hide the taskbar in tablet mode and then my excel sheet including the bottom tabs appeared above the taskbar